# How can I see the most popular questions of all time?

Tags: support, questions

I think that it used to be possible to see the most popular questions of all time, but I'm not sure whether it's possible anymore.

I would very much like to know how to find the most popular questions in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: how do you define popular? Number of views? Number of votes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want to see a single view of popular questions across all Stack Exchange websites, or for a particular SE site?

If you're looking for the latter, go to the site's main page, click "Questions" in the left navigation bar, then click in the middle click the "More", and there click "Score". You'll end up with a list of all questions, sorted by votes. [Here's that page on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes). I believe that page respects your ignored tags, so remove any of yours to view *all* questions.

If the button isn't available, simply append `/questions?sort=votes` to the domain (ex. `https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes`).

Comment: oh weird, i looked for it in superuser.com and couldn't find it

Comment: And if I want to see the former?